# SSH Tunnel to Memcached not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, memcached

I have created a SSH Tunnel to my memcached server as follows:

```
 ssh -f -N user@56.55.55.56 -L 11211:127.0.0.1:11211
```

When i do netstat on my machine i get the following:
So far looks good.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      976/ssh
```

The issue shows up when I telnet to the server as follows:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So I went to the memcached server and tailed the auth.log file and found this message overytime i try to telnet to the server:

```
Apr  4 13:56:06 vmcachd sshd[1410]: error: connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 11211: failed.
```

Does anyone know what is the issue, I have a similar setup with postgresql and it works perfectly fine! Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure memcached is running on the server?

Comment: Hi Tero, yes it is running I have included the output of netstat -tulpn

`tcp        0      0 192.168.3.106:11211     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1031/memcached`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your help, I have solved the issue by reinstalling the latest Centos 7 operating system with the latest memcache server, everything works perfectly now. Before my memcache server was running on an older version of Debian 6.0.6/squeeze, not sure if that had anything to do with it, but surely the reinstall of the latest os solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

do a:

```
 ssh -f -N user@56.55.55.56 netstat -putan
```

should show you something  LISTENing in 127.0.0.1:11211  (or 0.0.0.0:11211) check the column "Local Address"

if you see something else (like listening in another interface) there are 2 options:

1. you change the tunnel to listen to that interface i.e.: `ssh -f -N user@56.55.55.56 -L 11211:192.168.3.106:11211`
2. make memcache listen to 127.0.0.1 i.e.: you start the service with `memcached -l 127.0.0.1` (or it's corresponding /etc/default/memcached in ubuntu/debian)

Comment: Hello, I run that command but it does not return anything. I also run this command on my another server where I do ssh tunnel to Postgresql and it also comes back with nothing. That postgresql ssh tunnel that i have set up works perfectly.

Comment: postgress listens in 0.0.0.0:5432 by default. Memcache doesn't (it chooses an specific address, which I guess in your case is 192.168.3.106) can you paste the output of `ssh -f -N user@56.55.55.56 netstat -putan` ?